# alert dialog goes after a short time

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am usint the alert Dialog in my app it  shows up and it goes only if I   pressed the return button 
 can I make it shows for  short time and then it automatically goes like the Toast

Comment: That isn't really the purpose of a Dialog, but you could start a thread timer, then dismiss the dialog when finished

Comment: You could implement a custom toast too.

Comment: how can I do this am sorry but am now to the android studio I don't know much

Comment: Note: Android Studio is just where you write the code, some people still use Eclipse to write apps. What you don't know much about would be the Android code, or the SDK.

Comment: yeah that's what I meant

Comment: As a recommendation : use **Snackbar**

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code be helpful! ;) **UPDATED**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    AlertDialog ad;
    AlertDialog.Builder adb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        adb.setTitle("TITLE");
        adb.setMessage("MSG");
        ad = adb.create();
        ad.show();


        new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

                ad.dismiss();

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"YourToast",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }.start();

    }
}
```